# React native camera recording adds memory to ram resulting in crash - ios

Tags: ios, react-native, memory-leaks, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

App has 5 steps. Steps 1 and 2 are for recording videos and 3, 4, and 5 are for capturing photos(react-native-camera is used for all 5 steps). In each step, the captured source is uploaded and deleted from local cache memory using react-native-fetch-blob. However the memory is still adding up in RAM for each capture resulting in a crash. I ran profiling from XCode and found the memory spike happening during capture and not clearing after the source is deleted from cache memory. Any idea to free RAM space from adding up will greatly help. Crashing is a problem happening only in iOS.

[image]

Below are tools i use,

- react - 16.13.1
- react-native - 0.63.2
- react-native-camera - ^3.40.0   // for recording photos and videos
- react-native-fetch-blob - ^0.10.8   // for deleting photos and videos
  stored locally after the file is uploaded